# Is "any of them" used with a singular or plural verb?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I'm posting this question to settle a debate.

Is the sentence, **"If there are three of an unparalleled thing, is any of them truly unparalleled?"** correct? The sentence throws me off because the first clause has a plural subject, but the second clause has a singular subject. My personal preference would be to make the subjects in both clauses plural. I.e. **"If there are three of an unparalleled thing, are any of them truly unparalleled?"**

On the other hand, adding "one" sounds okay too. I.e. **"If there are three of an unparalleled thing, is any *one* of them truly unparalleled?"** The addition of "one" lessens the ambiguity over whether the subject is singular or not.

Comment: Okay, go ahead.

Comment: "Yes, one of them **is**." "Yes, two of them **are**." Now decide if there's anything still odd with the original sentence.

Comment: What? You are not making any sense.

Comment: @Kris The OP’s asking about whether the “any” is considered plural or not. “One is” and “two are?” That’s completely irrelevant. Do read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using singular and plural subjects in different clauses in the same sentence: as you yourself observe, we can say things like "If there are three of an unparalleled thing, is any one of them truly unparalleled?"

I think the reason for uncertainty about whether "any of [plural noun]" should take singular or plural verb agreement is because the noun in the prepositional phrase is plural in form, but the word *any* is not, and semantically it could be considered either singular or plural. For comparison, the construction "which of [plural noun]" takes singular or plural agreement depending on its meaning: we could say "Which of these squares is red" or "Which of these squares are red" depending on whether we expect a singular or plural answer.

Apparently, both usages are fairly common, but it's more common or more commonly accepted to use a singular verb with "any of [plural noun]". See CowperKettle's answer to the question "[How to use “any of”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34322/how-to-use-any-of)" on ELL SE:

> I did some googling, and it turns out any of your options **is** admitted: here's a link to [a grammar blog post][1]. I quote:
>
> > **Any of** can be followed by a verb in the singular or plural: "If **any of** your friends **want/wants** to come, they are welcome." (Plural is preferred in everyday language, singular is more formal)
>
> Or, as the same issue it treated in [a grammar rule sheet][2] at a New Zealand university site,
>
> > When **any of** is followed by a countable plural noun, the verb can be in either singular or plural form, but a singular verb is more common in a formal style: "If **any of** your friends **is/are** interested, let me know."

Unfortunately, both of the links seem to be broken, so I haven't reproduced them.

I found a post with a relevant quotation from the [archive](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00321.html) of the Pearson Longman [Grammar Exchange Questions and Answers Newsgroup](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/). Rachel posted a message with the following quotation (I have not checked the quoted source directly):

> "When *none, neither, either* and *any* are followed by "of + plural noun/pronoun," they are normally used with singular verbs in a formal style in British English. Plural verbs are common in informal British usage and generally in American English.
>
> None of the cures really works. (formal British)
>
> None of the cures really work. (informal British; American)
>
> Neither of my brothers has/ have been outside England.
>
> Has/Have either of them been seen recently?
>
> If any of the children gets/ get hungry, they can have an orange."

(Michael Swan, *Practical English Usage,* Second Edition (Oxford University Press, 1995. Page 534)

Comment: Could be simpler than that.

Comment: @Kris: I don't understand what you mean!

Comment: Please see my comment at OP. This is an [ell.se] question.

Comment: I don't understand, either.

Comment: @posfan12 “Any …” can be either singular or plural. If you expect the “any” to be _one_, use a singular verb; if you expect it to be _at least one_, use a plural verb. Plural “any” is generally more common in American English.